# Field Service - How to customize the 'create booking' form on the Schedule Board page?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I would like to edit the field that appear in that create booking form as the options to select a start and end time only appear when the view is changed to hourly.

I've tried examining the tables I thought it would be set up on to see if I can find the form there, but I'm not 100% sure which table it is linked to. Is there any way to find out which table this is linked to just in case I've been looking at the wrong one? Also, I know that this is a URL and not a page, which i'm not familiar with...

Thank you in advance!

I've tried to review some of the table forms, and board settings with no luck.